# App prediction using node.js with express router

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb

I have been given an assignment and a four days time to complete it.

I have to write code using Node.js with express router to tell whether a given app(say X) is installed or un-installed and if uninstalled then predict the number of days since uninstall. It is assumed that the data for Android devices is stored in a MongoDB instance.

The problem is that I neither know Node.js and MongoDB. I only know basics of Javascript. Can anyone tell me what should I study to solve the above problem. I have only four days left to complete the assignment.

I know I can google and study everything. But I can easily get carried away off-topic and couldn't complete the assignment in due date. Please help.

Comment: Please tell me why there is downvote. I am not asking for solution. I am asking how should I proceed.

Comment: Not down voted however, this post may help: http://www.sitepoint.com/create-movie-recommendation-app-prediction-io-implementation/

Comment: +1 (Not down voted) You need to google about how to node with mongo (tons of how to...) https://codeforgeek.com/2015/08/restful-api-node-mongodb/ and look for already done NPMs such : https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-idevice - Goos luck